# how to find a string in memory having ARM instructions ARDP and LDR?

Tags: disassemblers, ios, arm64

*hello, I disassembled the request sent to the game server, I need to change the symbol, but I don’t know its memory address. Help me understand the **ADRP** and **LDR** instructions, I need to understand what address will be assigned to the register **"x1"**.*[image]

*my disassembly experience is very small, i will be happy for any help.*

will this user's question help me? [getting function address by reading ADRP and ADD instruction values](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15418/getting-function-address-by-reading-adrp-and-add-instruction-values)

Comment: I looked at similar examples in the code, there are nop everywhere but I don't know why. The address that turned out went beyond the boundaries of the program (I disassembled the unity engine)
I was told to look in the debugger for what the address is, but the debugger does not work.

Comment: Given that the architecture is arm64 (you didn't say it). From this post, ADRP will set the `x8` value to `pc + 0x2d71000`, then zero out the lower 12 bit. Then `nop` will do nothing (wonder if it's a hole for debugging?) Then `ldr x1, [x8, 0x250]` will load the value in the memory address `x8 + 0x250`. If your program has correct address (the address in the left size of the picture, provide that you don't have some kind of randomized address), then the value in address `0x4151250` in memory will be loaded to `x1` register. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `I was told to look in the debugger for what the address is, but the debugger does not work.` What debugger are you using?

Comment: im use Cutter disassembler

Comment: Can you be specific about `does not work`? WDYM by `does not work`?

Comment: there is a similar question about ARDP but instead of LDR there is ADD, I tested and ADD is also suitable in my case

Comment: when you click on the debug button, the download occurs, but the program is not executed. only emulator works

Comment: will this user's question help me? https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15418/getting-function-address-by-reading-adrp-and-add-instruction-values

Comment: I think not possible without knowing the base of the program. In the link you put, OP has `ADD` instruction after get the `x8` register's value (we also got that value), so he can add it. In your case, you need to load value from memory, it can be the value that is produced by another function in the program (for example global variable?)

Comment: thanks for the help, I wrote about this issue on 2 more sites, maybe this is a very problematic task

Comment: In case someone need it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73092001/how-to-find-address-in-memory-without-debugger